# All My Files Gone after switching branches

Tags: git

i had a project which was linked to a github repo. and i stopped pushing the code for few weeks. But within these weeks i've made whole lot of changes in the repo but didn't commit or push it to github. Now, i suddenly thought let's commit this code. then, i created a new branch (didn't commit anything) then goback to the main(default) branch and BOOM! all my code updated files are gone. Only new uncommited files are in the codebase but the updated files are changed to the main branches last commit.
How do i recover from it?

how do i get my uncommited files back?

Comment: git won't help you. If you never commited the changes or at least added them to the index then git doesn't know about them. Your best bet is to check if your IDE has a "local history" feature and restore the files from there. If it doesn't, then check your backups and/or snapshots. If you don't have those then I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: "*within these weeks i've made whole lot of changes in the repo but didn't commit or push it to github*" is the core of the problem. We can't change the past but at least now you know what **not to** do next time.

Comment: thank you all. I really f-ed up this time. **Lesson Learned** there's no goin back

Comment: Still, check the duplicate I linked to, it has some possible suggestions on how you *might* still be able to get to it (outside of using git).

Comment: What do you mean by "go back to main branch"? Which commands did you use to do that?

Comment: Normal git client should have warned you that you have uncommitted changes. How did you reacted to that message?

Comment: Did you commit the files on your new branch? Did you stash the changes? Switching branches (with `git switch` or `git checkout`) will not remove uncommitted changes (but `git clean` or `git reset` might)

Comment: @KentoYamazaki If all you did was `git switch`, there has to be a way to get your files back. If you tell us exactly what commands you used, we would be able to help.

Comment: I used the visual tool from vscode from creating new branches and switching. But in the process i didn't commit anything. I just created few branches and switched between them @Caleb

Comment: @KentoYamazaki I haven't used that before, but that's interesting.... If you created branches on the blob that your current working directory was sitting on, then your changes shouldn't have gone anywhere. The only way that could have happened is if you created branches on a different blob. And, even though I haven't used this tool before, I am certain that it should have prevented you from switching, or at least warned you before it let you switch. If I were you, I would check your stashed changes and see if anything comes up. Maybe you accidentally stashed them.